# MySQL Lock Timeout Exceeded When Server Time Updates

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL 5.6 DB server providing service to 10 clients.  The clients poll the database server for records to process.  We were having intermittent issues where all of the clients would suddenly generate "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" errors, all of them at the same time.  During troubleshooting one of these events we noted that on the server (Windows Server 2008R2) that at the moment the clients generated the error the server time had changed.  We took note for the next time.

Today the next time occurred.  9 out of the 10 clients generated the error and sure enough, when we checked the Event Viewer on the server the server time had changed 1 second forward at the exact time the errors were generated.

Can someone explain:

1. Why this is happening?
2. Recommend a way to prevent it?

We are already handling deadlock errors and it's actually not clear where in the program this error is coming from.  The clients do not poll the server simultaneously but psuedo randomly in approximate 10 second intervals so it's baffling to us that so many would generate the error at the same moment.

Thanks,
Pablo

Comment: have you gone through innodb status log? Is there any task is scheduled on server like complete backup or etc.?

Comment: @BK435 - Updates and inserts are happening all the time via a web service which is running on the same server.  The web service doesn't get the error and we already handle normal deadlocks in the client so that it retries.  This is something else going on I think.  Also, sorry for the delay in replying... for some reason I was not able to add tags or comments in the Firefox version I was using at work.

Comment: @Amogh - No, I haven't gone through the log but there are no scheduled tasks running when this happens.  It also happens at different times of the day, basically whenever the server time is is synced.

Answer (score 0):

What may be happening is some thread is holding lock on some record/table (may be an scheduled task is there to take backup of DB which is generating locks) for too long, and your thread is being timed out. As I said in comments please go through innodb status log for more details.

One way to avoid this is if you are using InnoDB storage engine then fine tune your transaction isolation level.

Check transaction isolation level by executing `SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;`

If you see any of these as `REPEATABLE READ` which is defauld for InnoDB set it to READ COMMITTED using

`SET tx_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';` and `SET GLOBAL tx_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';`

Comment: FYI changing isolation level has serious consequences. This setting should not be changed lightly.

Comment: Again, I don't think this is a standard deadlock issue. We already know how to handle those and they are handled gracefully.  In this case it's an abrupt end to the connection.  It doesn't even seem to be just when the SELECT is running.  Looking at the client logs some of them are essentially idle when it happens, or they try to run the SELECT portion just after it happens.